# Cannot run basic commands in the terminal since Ubuntu crash

Tags: command-line, vmware

I am using Ubuntu with Ubuntu 64-bit -VMware Workstation 15 Player. A few days ago, while I was running Ubuntu, I had to log out of my windows user due to an error, which led to a crash (everything froze) in the virtual machine. I 'fixed' that by clicking on the pause sign (top left corner of the added pictures) and restarted the machine, now it is running again. But ever since I cannot use commands such as 'll' anymore.

I noticed the change in the terminal, which usually had my hostname in the headline and the name itself highlighted in every line, so I created a new sudo user (those commands work) for test purposes and when l switch the user to it, it looks the way it did before just, so I assume I accidentally changed something concerning my old user I cannot undo myself.

Those are the differences in appearance: 
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Besides, merry christmas ( : .

Comment: Welcome to [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com)! i think your Ubuntu not have crash! try see your `.bashrc` with run `cat ~/.bashrc |grep ll` and removed `#` on the `#alias ll=<commands>` saved and run `source ~/.bashrc`. you can try again `$ ll` and see what happened!!!

Comment: Maybe `.bashrc` is messed up. No aliases, wrong PS1.

Comment: Perhaps! please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1104220/edit) your question to including the output of `cat ~/.bashrc |grep PS1`??

Comment: Oh I added the answer already, thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

thanks alot for the fast replies. There wasn't anything wrong at all as abu-ahmed al-khatiri initially suggested (is there a way to tag people?). I have made a stupid mistake the last time I was logged in, which was before the 'crash', which resulted in the problem I had once I relogged. So, your suggestions about the .bashrc led me to the solution. It wasn't the .bashrc or anything that was corrupted, it was me trying to 'tidy up' the folder structure where I put all the files (.bashrc included) into a folder that was supposed to contain everything I do not use actively but might need at a later stage. I was looking for .bashrc via 'll' and while I could not enter the command, pressing tab for autocompletion showed me everything was still there so I found my way to .bashr and the idea that putting everything into a folder might have been a bad idea. I moved it back into the home directory and it works again. Thanks everyone for the help.